# Increase number of processed samples in Simulink

Tags: matlab, real-time, signal-processing, simulink

I'm pretty new to Simulink and I was wondering if the following thing was possible somehow:

I have a signal of let's say 10000 data points.
On this signal I want to run a certain algorithm, however said algorithm needs exactly 1000 samples to work properly.

Now with normal matlab functions this is no problem. You cut the signal in 10 pieces, perform the algorithm for each one, stitch the processed parts back together and you get your result.

In Simulink however this creates sort of a problem, since (to my understanding right now) Simulinks blocks work sample per sample (one sample in, one sample out). So I don't have the necessary data to perform the algortihm within a block.

Is there any way to increase the number of processed samples per block?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but this might be what you are looking for: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/dsp/ref/buffer.html

Comment: Also look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/signalfromworkspace.html if you are importing data from MATLAB. You can specify "Samples per frame" to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Reshape 10,000 data points with 1000 samples and create Column wise data

lets say 
data = [1 2 3 4 5 6], convert

```
 data = [1 4  
         2 5
         3 6]
```

Now, define sample time for lets say 1 sec, use fromworkspace blocks. In this example 2 (No of column), with each workspace block format a array as [t data(:,1)],[t data(:,2)] where t = [1 2 3], multiples of sampletime.

```
On Simulink Model, set running time equal to 3 sec as there are 3 data points and store output via to workspace block
```